# Can't tell if this is a race condition

Tags: node.js, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to build a simple chat server(practice), with nodejs. I have a global var chatRooms, and it can be changed or read by all requests to the server. I am trying to figure out if I am possibly causing some race conditions. I am also using sockets via the node net module.

```
var net = require('net');
var chatRooms = {fender:[]};

function enterRoom(socket, room){
  charRooms[room].push(socket.username);
}

function leaveRoom(socket, room){
  var indexOfUser = chatRooms[room].indexOf(socket.username);
  chatRoom[room].splice(indexOfUser, 1);
}
```

so, I am trying to figure out this situation:
user A joins chat room fender: - chatRoom looks like {fender:['A']}
user B joins chat room fender: - chatRoom looks like {fender:['A', 'B']}

user B and A want to leave the room, and do so at the same time: 
user B indexOfUser === 1;
user A indexOfUser === 0;
user A splices chatRooms gobal var, before user B does.
global ChatRoom var now looks like (fender:['B']}
user B indexOfUser no longer === 1
so when user B splices ChatRooms it will do so using the wrong index.

Is something like this possible, or the single threaded nature of node prevents this from happening.

What is cant figure out is if these two lines of code will be problematic

```
var indexOfUser = chatRooms[room].indexOf(socket.username);
// another request alters charRooms before the next line of code is reached.
chatRoom[room].splice(indexOfUser, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single threaded nature of node prevents that. Every full block of code is strongly isolated, i.e. no other code can run in "parallel".

Comment: I think I got it, so if request 1 is currently in function leaveRoom(), and at the same time a few more requests to leave a chat room come in at the same time, then these new requests will only be served once request 1 is done?

Comment: @DaverMuzaffar Yes, exactly. Until request 1 finishes it's job they will be queued and wait for their turn.